# Google Sign-in doesn't call the data-onsuccess method on mobile browsers in iOS

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I have webapp that uses Google Sign-in to authenticate a user. The code works fine in multiple browsers in my Windows PC. However, it doesn't work in Chrome or Safari browser in my iPhone 6 Plus.

This is what happens when I open the page in my browser:

1. It loads the default page.
2. My server gets that request and redirects it to /login.
3. The browser follows the redirect to the login page. It shows the Google's Sign in button.
4. If I click on that, it opens another page, and once I login there, it comes back to this page and the button now changes to Sign**ed** in.

But after this, it is supposed to execute my onSignIn function and validate the id token. It doesnt' appear to execute that function as that request never comes to my server.

The actual app is in github.
This is the relevant javascript file: https://github.com/prasannasv/isha-carpool/blob/master/src/main/resources/static/js/signin.js

This is the relevant html page for login: https://github.com/prasannasv/isha-carpool/blob/master/src/main/webapp/template/carpool_app.soy#L7-L63

I have made sure my mobile browser (Safari) third-party cookies setting is "Allow Always".

Comment: Did you figure this out? Does it work if you move the `<script>` tags from `<body>` to `<head>`?

Comment: So, without any further changes, the code currently works in my mobile browser. This is a different phone though. So, I think it has to do something with the browser setting than anything in the server side.